# Visibility.Visible not working

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am creating and binding columns/elements into my datagrid.

I created a `DataGridTemplateColumn`and in that column i'm inserting a `TextBox` element.

```
DataGridTemplateColumn columnFeedbackSupplier = new DataGridTemplateColumn();

var dockPanel = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(DockPanel));
DataTemplate cellTemplate = new DataTemplate();

FrameworkElementFactory factoryText = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBox));
Binding bindText = new Binding("Supplier");
bindText.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
factoryText.SetValue(TextBox.TextProperty, bindText);
//This is not working
factoryText.SetValue(TextBox.VisibilityProperty, Visibility.Visible);
//
cellTemplate.VisualTree = factoryText;
dockPanel.AppendChild(factoryText);
cellTemplate.VisualTree = dockPanel;
```

Now when I add the following line, it allows me to edit my selected cell, but it also hides my `TextBox` on my datagrid until I double click on that cell then my element is visible again. Once that cell loses focus, my `TextBox` is hidden again.

```
columnFeedbackSupplier.CellEditingTemplate = cellTemplate;
```

I can use the following line to make my `TextBox` always visible, but I would not be able to save my edited values into my datagrid.

```
columnFeedbackSupplier.CellTemplate = cellTemplate;
```

Is there a way to make my TextBox always visible, while using `CellEditingTemplate`?